# Second call told Cannot read property 'done' of undenfined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page with buttons. On the button click, the content is loaded  via Ajax request (see below). That loaded window has a dropdown select that has on change function that call ajax.

It works perfectly on the first click, but on the second one it says

> Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

but loads the "inProgressRequest in a false way.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my JS that called the main HTML head:

```
var inProgressRequest = false;

    
function makeRequest(u, d, t = 'POST', j = 'json'){
        if(inProgressRequest === false){
            return $.ajax({
                url: u,
                data: d,
                type: t,
                dataType: j,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    inProgressRequest = true;
                },
                complete: function () {
                    inProgressRequest = false;
                }
            }).done(function(r){
                if(r.m){ showDialog(r.m.k, r.m.t, r.m.m); };
                if(r.fe){ ajaxFormError(r.fe); }
                if(r.close === true){
                    $('.form-bgr').trigger('click');
                }
                inProgressRequest = false;
            }).fail(function(x){
                console.log(x.responseText);
                showDialog('e', 'Ajax hívási hiba', 'A szervernek a kérelemet nem sikerült futtatnia. <br>Hibakód: <span>('+x.status+') '+x.statusText+'</span>');
                inProgressRequest = false;
            });
        } else {
            showDialog('w', 'Figyelmeztetés', 'Jelenleg folyamatban van egy kérelem. Kérjük próbálja újra egy kicsit később!');
        }
    };
```

The page where i call makeRequest:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HM CRM</title>
        <!-- Meta Information starts -->
        <meta name="description" content="Easy management for HM">
        <meta name="keywords" content="admin">
        <meta name="author" content="Tóth András">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
        <meta name="dcterms.rightsHolder" content="Tóth András">
        <meta name="dcterms.dateCopyrighted" content="2017">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Meta Information ends -->
        <!--[if IE]>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css?1626184266">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fluid.css?1626184266">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rebirth.css?1626184266">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css?1626184266">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome-free-5.2.0-web/css/all.min.css?1626184266">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/jquery/datetimepicker-master/jquery.datetimepicker.css?1626184266">
        <link href="/design/quest/admin-page-icon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png"> 
        
        <script src="/scripts/jquery/version-3.6.0/jquery-3.6.0.min.js?1626184266"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js?1626184266"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/custom/counter.js?1626184266"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/custom/custom-jquery.js?1626184266"></script>
        <script src="/scripts/jquery/datetimepicker-master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js?1626184266"></script>
        
        <script>
            var adminPath = 'http://crm.hu/admin';
            Count(3600,'logout-time');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click','a[href="#"]', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
                });
                
                $(document).on('click','.to-the-top', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
                    return false;
                });
                
                $(document).on('click', '#mobil-menu-button', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#ul-moduls").slideToggle();
                    return false;
                });
                
                $('.contant-navigation:hidden').show();
                
                /* ADD CONTACT TOO */
                $(document).on('change', '#add_person', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#add_person_to').slideToggle();
                    return false;
                });
                
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-box" class="hc-flex-row">
            <div id="main-left-box" class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-03 xl-02">
                <div id="logout-time">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fas fa-clock fa-fw"></i> 
                        60:00                    </span>
                </div>
                <nav id="navigation-moduls">
                    <a id="mobil-menu-button" href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-fw"></i></a>
                    <ul id="ul-moduls"><li><a class="selected" href="/admin/main"><i class="fas fa-home fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a></li><li><a  href="/admin/contacts"><i class="fas fa-book fa-fw"></i> Kapcsolatok</a></li><li><a  href="/admin/offers"><i class="fa fa-file fa-fw fa-fw"></i> Ajánlatok</a></li><li><a  href="/admin/users"><i class="fa fa-users fa-fw fa-fw"></i> Felhasználók</a></li><li><a  href="/admin/options"><i class="fas fa-cogs fa-fw"></i> Beállítások</a></li><li><a  href="/admin/logout"><i class="fas fa-power-off fa-fw"></i> Kilépés</a></li></ul>                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="main-right-box" class="hc-flex-row xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-09 xl-10">
                <h1 class="page-title"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Dashboard</h1><script>
    var u = '/admin/main/ajax';
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* ÚJ FELADAT */
        $(document).on('click', '.create-task', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            makeRequest(u, 'action=create_task_form').done(function(r){
                showFormBox(r.html);
            });
            return false;
        });
        
        /* ÚJ MEGJEGYZÉS */
        $(document).on('click', '.note-task', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).val();
            makeRequest(u, 'action=create_note_form&id='+id).done(function(r){
                showFormBox(r.html);
            });
            return false;
        });
        
        /* FELADAT ELVÉGEZVE */
        $(document).on('click', '.success-task', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).val();
            makeRequest(u, 'action=update_task&id='+id+'&task_update=1').done(function(r){
                refresh_task_and_projects(r);
            });
            return false;
        });
        
        /* FELADAT MEGHIÚSULT */
        $(document).on('click', '.failed-task', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).val();
            makeRequest(u, 'action=update_task&id='+id+'&task_update=2').done(function(r){
                refresh_task_and_projects(r);
            });
            return false;
        });
        
        function refresh_task_and_projects(r){
            if(r.lists_tasks){ $('#task-lists').empty().append(r.lists_tasks)}
            if(r.lists_projects){ $('#project-lists').empty().append(r.lists_projects)}
            if(r.lists_projects){ $('#completed-project-lists').empty().append(r.lists_completed_projects)}
            if(r.lists_projects){ $('#failed-project-lists').empty().append(r.lists_failed_projects)}
            $('.contant-navigation:hidden').show();
        }
    });
</script>
<div class="contant-navigation">
    <nav class="hc-flex-margin-row-03" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: -6px;">
        <button type="button" value="0" class="submit-button-2 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto create-task"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Új feladat létrehozása</button>
    </nav>
</div>

<section class="section-box">
    <div class="section-box-inside">
        <article class="section-info-article">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> Feladataim</h2>
        </article>
        <div id="task-lists">
            
            <div id="list-header" class="list-header-row hc-flex-margin-row-05">
                <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-04">Feladat</div>
                <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-02 xl-03">Határidő</div>
                <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-02 xl-02">Kiosztva</div>
                <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-03 xl-03 company-actions">Műveletek</div>
            </div><ul class="list-row-ul">
                    <li class="list-row r">
                        <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-05" style="align-items:center;">
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-04 task-rows">
                                <div class="task-subinfo">Tricel Ltd.</div>
                                <div class="task-maininfo">1. Kapcsolatfelvétel - <a href="#" class="contact-ajax-info">Chris Redfield</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-03 task-duedate task-dudate-late">
                                2021.07.08 15:13 <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-02">
                                Tulajdonos + NEVEK  
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-02 xl-03 company-actions">
                                <div class="contant-navigation">
                                    <nav class="hc-flex-margin-row-03" style="width:100%;">
                                        <button value="1" class="submit-button-4 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto note-task"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Jegyzet</button><button value="1" class="submit-button-2 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto success-task"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Elvégezve</button><button value="1" class="submit-button-3 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto failed-task"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Meghiúsult</button>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </li>
                
                    <li class="list-row y">
                        <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-05" style="align-items:center;">
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-04 task-rows">
                                <div class="task-subinfo">Kiss Kacsa Bt.</div>
                                <div class="task-maininfo">3. Ajánlatküldés - <a href="#" class="contact-ajax-info">Gipsz János</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-03 task-duedate ">
                                2021.07.14 14:45 
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-02">
                                Tulajdonos + NEVEK  
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-02 xl-03 company-actions">
                                <div class="contant-navigation">
                                    <nav class="hc-flex-margin-row-03" style="width:100%;">
                                        <button value="138" class="submit-button-4 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto note-task"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Jegyzet</button><button value="138" class="submit-button-2 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto success-task"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Elvégezve</button><button value="138" class="submit-button-3 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-04 me-auto failed-task"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> Meghiúsult</button>
                                    </nav>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </li>
                </ul">        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- LEADEK -->
<section class="section-box">
    <div class="section-box-inside">
        <article class="section-info-article">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> Folyamatban lévő projektek</h2>
        </article>
        <div id="project-lists">
            
            <div id="list-header" class="list-header-row hc-flex-margin-row-05">
                <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-05 xl-03">Project</div>
                <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-02 xl-09">Folyamat</div>
            </div><ul class="list-row-ul">
                    <li class="list-row y">
                        <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-05" style="align-items:center;">
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-03 project-rows">
                                <div class="project-subinfo">Új vállalkozás vizsgálat (4)</div>
                                <div class="project-maininfo"><a href="#">Kiss Kacsa Bt.</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-09">
                                <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-02" style="width:100%;"><div class="lead-step success step1 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">1. Kapcsolatfelvétel </span><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div><div class="lead-step success step2 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">2. Bemutatkozás </span><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div><div class="lead-step in-progress step3 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">3. Ajánlatküldés </span><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i></div><div class="lead-step step4 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">4. Megrendelés</span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div><div class="lead-step step5 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-12 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">5. Kifizetés</span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                
                    <li class="list-row y">
                        <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-05" style="align-items:center;">
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-03 project-rows">
                                <div class="project-subinfo">Új vállalkozás vizsgálat (3)</div>
                                <div class="project-maininfo"><a href="#">Tricel Ltd.</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-09">
                                <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-02" style="width:100%;"><div class="lead-step in-progress step1 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">1. Kapcsolatfelvétel </span><i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i></div><div class="lead-step step2 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">2. Bemutatkozás</span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div><div class="lead-step step3 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">3. Ajánlatküldés</span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div><div class="lead-step step4 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-06 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">4. Megrendelés</span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div><div class="lead-step step5 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-percent-20 me-percent-20 la-12 xl-percent-20"><span class="status-bar-text">5. Kifizetés</span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul">        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="section-box">
    <div class="section-box-inside">
        <article class="section-info-article">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> Lezárt projektek</h2>
        </article>
        <div id="completed-project-lists">
                    </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="section-box">
    <div class="section-box-inside">
        <article class="section-info-article">
            <h2><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i> Meghiúsult projektek</h2>
        </article>
        <div id="failed-project-lists">
                    </div>
    </div>
</section>


    

            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="main-footer">
            <a href="#" class="to-the-top"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i></a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

After i click +Új Feladat létrehozása load below content:

```
<div class="form-box-155353843" style="display: block;"><div class="form-bgr"></div><div class="form-inner"><div class="form-inner-box form-inner-box-on-air"><script src="/scripts/jquery/validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('hu');
        jQuery('#due_date').datetimepicker({
            showSecond: true,
            format:'Y-m-d H:i',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            timeFormat: 'h:m',
            step: 15,
            weeks: true,
            dayOfWeekStart: 1,
            closeOnDateSelect: true,
            minDate:0,
            maxDate:'+1971/01/02'//tomorrow is maximum date calendar
        });
        
        $(document).on('change', '#project_id', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $('#project_id').val();
            makeRequest('/admin/main/ajax', 'action=get_project_task_list&id='+id).done(function(r){
                if(r.task_types){
                    var items = '';
                    $('#project_start').empty();
                    $.each(r.task_types, function(i, v) {
                        items += '<option value="'+i+'">'+v+'</option>';
                    });
                    $('#project_start').append(items);
                }
            }).fail(function(){
                console.log('hiba');
            });
            return false;
        });
        
        /* FORM VALIDÁLÁS */
        $("#create-task-form").validate({
            errorElement: "span",
            rules: {
                due_date: { required: true, minlength:16, maxlength: 16}
            },
            messages: {
                due_date:{
                    required: "Határidő mező megadása kötelező.",
                    minlength: "Határidő mező legalább 16 karakter hosszú kell hogy legyen.",
                    maxlength: "Határidő mező hossza nem haladhatja meg a(z) 16 karaktert."
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var d = $('#create-task-form').serialize();
                makeRequest('/admin/main/ajax', d+'&action=create_task_submit').done(function(r){});
            }
        });
        
    });
</script>
<form action="http://crm.hu/admin/main/ajax" class="form_class" id="create-task-form" autocomplete="off" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" novalidate="novalidate">
<section class="section-box">
    <div class="section-box-inside">
        <article class="section-info-article">
            <h2>Új feladat megadása</h2>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Kérjük adja meg az új feladat részleteit. A <span class="required">*</span>-al jelölt mezők kitöltése kötelező!</p>
        </article>
        <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-03" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            
            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-05 form-row">
                <label for="project_id" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span>Projekt típusa:</label>                <select name="project_id" id="project_id" class="form-input">
<option value="1">Új vállalkozás vizsgálat</option>
<option value="2">Új ajánlat kiadás</option>
<option value="3">Vállalkozás újra vizsgálása</option>
<option value="4">Napi hideghívás</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-04 form-row">
                <label for="project_start" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span>Indulási pont:</label>                <select name="project_start" id="project_start" class="form-input">
<option value="" selected="selected">Kérjük válasszon!</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-03 form-row">
                <label for="due_date" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span>Határidő:</label>                <input type="text" name="due_date" value="" id="due_date" minlength="16" maxlength="16" placeholder="Határidő" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="form-input">
            </div>
            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-12 me-12 la-12 xl-12 form-row">
                <label for="company_contact_id" class="form-label"><span class="required">*</span>Cég és kapcsolattartó:</label>                <select name="company_contact_id" id="company_contact_id" class="form-input">
<option value="7">Hungaro Management Kft. - Lakatos Márk (lakatos@mark.hu)</option>
<option value="6">Jézus Szíve Bt. - Jézus Krisztus (jezus@istenfia.hu)</option>
<option value="5">Kiss Kacsa Bt. - Gipsz János (gipsz@jakab.hu)</option>
<option value="9">Teszt 2 - Kázmér Huba (kazmer@huba.hu)</option>
<option value="3">Tricel Ltd. - Chris Redfield (chris.redfield@t2icell.hu)</option>
<option value="4">Tricel Ltd. - Chris Redfield (chris.redfield@taicell.hu)</option>
<option value="2">Tricel Ltd. - Chris Redfield (chris.redfield@tricell.hu)</option>
<option value="1">Umbrella Corporation - Albert Wesker (albert.wesker@umbrella.com)</option>
<option value="8">Valaki Bt. - Jakab Pista (jakab.pista@entendre.hu)</option>
</select>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <article class="section-info-article">
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Kérjük jelölje be az összes olyan felhasználót akinek ki szeretné osztani a project feladatait.</p>
        </article>
        <div class="hc-flex-margin-row-03" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-06 me-04 la-04 task-user-lists"><input type="checkbox" name="ordered_users" value="8" id="user_id8" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-right: 6px;">
<label for="user_id8" class="form-label" style="position:inherit; font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px; padding: 0px 2px; text-transform:none;">Nagy Bence</label></div><div class="hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-06 me-04 la-04 task-user-lists"><input type="checkbox" name="ordered_users" value="9" id="user_id9" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-right: 6px;">
<label for="user_id9" class="form-label" style="position:inherit; font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px; padding: 0px 2px; text-transform:none;">Pogácsás Mariann</label></div>        </div>
        <nav class="hc-flex-margin-row-03" style="margin-top: 5px; justify-content: flex-end;">
            <button type="submit" class="submit-button-2 hc-flex-column xs-12 sm-auto me-auto"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Új feladat rögzítése</button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>

</form>        </div></div></div>
```

After loaded when i change dropdown load the second dropdown opt correctly. After i (removed) the content that loaded by "+Újfeladat létrehozása", then click again, load content again, BUT now when i try change dropdown got "Cannot read property 'done' of undenfined" error and jump to False way on makeRequest()

Any solution?